# Is better sati cause to better memory?

Tags: karma, reference-request, science, sati

Did Lord Buddha tell something about this ? (Relationship between sati and memory)

There was a monk in Buddha's time who is enlightened but didn't have a strong memory. To be enlightened, some has to have a strong sati.

Comment: What is better sati?

Comment: I mean Well developed sati / awareness.

Comment: Do you have more specific references on your story about this monk?

Comment: That monk is [Arahat. Chulla Panthaka](https://suttacentral.net/tha-ap16/en/walters) thero.

Answer (score 2):

Normal memory is bound up in craving (e.g., "I remember that pretty face"). Or normal memory is bound up in aversion (e.g., "You ALWAYS pick on me!"). Or normal memory is bound up in delusion (e.g., "I want to be like that famous person").

The memory of sati requires awareness without craving, aversion or delusion. That's surprisingly difficult and requires steady and constant practice.

> [AN5.14:4.1](https://suttacentral.net/an5.14/en/sujato#an5.14:4.1): And what is the power of mindfulness?  It’s when a noble disciple is mindful. They have utmost mindfulness and alertness, and can remember and recall what was said and done long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Good householder,

The question is a little hard to understand since sati means remembering, keeping in mind, but maybe this helps a little to clearing certain common missunderstandings: [Mindfulness Defined](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/headandhearttogether/Section0009_en.html) and [The Agendas of Mindfulness](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/agendas_en.html). Bad memory of course means weak sati and viciversa. So don't use google and search-machines (sati killer, training lazyness and make dependend) :-) but sort and remember where what to find.

As for the Path, actually less of just knowledge needs to be remembered, so the proper attention on what to keep in mind, as a skill, is much more importand for paths and fruits.

"What is skilful, what unskilful, what to hold on end develope, what to abound." Not much, or?

*(Note 5hat this is not given for trade, exchange, stacks but to escape from this wheel of dependency)*